# Setting name of array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, join

I would like to create an array in Perl that will have for name the values of two variables and, one of the two variables will have a value that is read from a file.

In the simplified case, how can I create an array with name `CCP` when `P` and `CC` are two separate variables?

So far I have joined the two using:

```
my $body='CC';
my $letter='P';
my $joined=$body . "$venue";
```

but I would like to actually create an array with name `@CCP`. The idea is that I will read different letters from a data file and then create the arrays that will have names given by joining 'CC' to the letters read from file.

Comment: This is a bad code smell, and an indication that you want a hash.

Comment: Thanks: I think I will re-write my code so to use a hash instead!

Comment: http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You *really* don't want to do that. How will you know what the array is called when you need to access it?

Use a hash, like this

```
my %data;

my $body   = 'CC';
my $letter = 'P';

$data{"$body$letter"} = [];
```

Comment: Do you mean `my %data` or am I missing something?

Comment: You're right. I was torn between using a hash or a hash reference, and ended up using both. Thanks!

Comment: I felt like a pro-Perl user when I noticed it... lol... I haven't thought about it but a hash might be better for what I need!